# ReactRouter:Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

The warning is `Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).`

Then it throw error `Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.` when `renderToString`

The whole code is:

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

let History = require("history");
let ReactRouter = require("react-router");

let match = ReactRouter.match;
let RouterContext = ReactRouter.RouterContext;
let Route = ReactRouter.Route;
let Router = ReactRouter.Router;
let Link = ReactRouter.Link;

let TestComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <button>test</button>
        );
    }
});

console.log(renderToString(<TestComponent/>));// a

let routes = [
    <Route path="/" component={TestComponent}/>
];

match({ routes, location: "/" }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }
    if (redirectLocation) {
        console.log(redirectLocation);
        return;
    }
    if (renderProps) {
        let component = <RouterContext {...renderProps} />;// b
        console.log(renderToString(component));// c
    }
});
```

The output at `a` is correct.

The warning is at `b`.

The error is at `c`.

The environment:

- react-router: 1.0.3
- history: 1.17.0
- react & react-dom: 0.14.3

The code is based on the document at https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs%2Fguides%2Fadvanced%2FServerRendering.md

Comment: If you do `console.log(RouterContext)` what does that give you?

Comment: I have the same issue. I use dynamic route. How to solve it ?

Answer (score 3):

I find no `RouterContext` in the source code of `react-router`.

but there is `RoutingContext`, so I use it, it is OK now.

thanks @limelights

It seems a bug of `react-router` https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2713